# Simple anti-aliasing function for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I need a very simple function to draw a bunch of lines with anti-aliasing. It has to follow Delphi paradigm: self contained and SYSTEM INDEPENDENT (no DLL hell), fast, simple. 
Anybody knows such a library?

Until now I have tried:

**WuLine**
swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1812
I don't think that the author of this code ever run it. It takes one second to draw a single line! It is obviously only for educational purposes :)

**Anti aliased drawing from TMetaFile**
Link: blog.synopse.info/post/2010/04/02/Antialiased-drawing-from-TMetaFile
Haven't really tried this yet (I may do it soon). It works only with TMetaFiles. It only loads an EMF file and draw it using anti aliasing functions. Plus, much code on that web site is only demonstrational/educational.

**Image32**
Very nice library - most complete until now. I might use it but it is overkill for what I need.
Disadvantages:
 - The footprint added to application is pretty big.
 - Really difficult to use.
 - You need to go really deep in its obscure documentation even for simple tasks. 
 - Demo code provided is way too complex.
 - Buggy!
 - No recent updates (to fix the bugs)

**Anti-Grain Geometry library**
The library needs a decent installer. The writers of the library are Linux/Mac users. The Windows implementation looks weird. I cannot say something else about the library itself.

**Xiaolin Wu's based function** (by Andreas Rejbrand)
Just see few posts below. Andreas Rejbrand provided a very compact solution. Best solution until now.

---

It looks like I have to explain why I don't like large 3rd party libraries and VCL's:

- you have to install them
- large library means large number of bugs which means
- you have to check for updates (and install them again)
- when you reinstall Delphi, you have to install them one more time (yes I hate installing VCLs)
- for VCLs, it means you have to load some extra icons in your already crowded palette.
- (sometimes) no support
- LARGE footprint added to your application size
- large library means (well not always but in most cases) difficult to use - more difficult than you need.
- (for external DLLs and API) your application becomes system-dependent - really nasty!

Comment: The interest of our SynGdiPlus library is that you can have your drawing code written in plain VCL TCanvas methods. Draw into a TMetaFileCanvas, then play it on a bitmap using our library. It's very fast, and works for much more than lines drawing. And footprint added to your application executable is negligible. You are welcome posting comments or questions about our library on our web site. And it's not only demonstrational/educational: it's used in real applications, for great rendering, with a lot of VCL TCanvas code (other programmers thought it was dot net drawing :)

Comment: GDI+ does fit my requirements (D7).

Comment: SynGdiPlus will work with D7. See our forum: http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=498#p498

Comment: @Bouchez - Sorry, I made a confusion with http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml which is also called GDI plus.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is not very hard to implement Xiaolin Wu's anti-aliasing line-rendering algorithm in Delphi. I used [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) as a reference when I wrote the following procedure (actually, I just translated the pseudo-code to Delphi and corrected a bug, and added support for a coloured background):

```
procedure DrawAntialisedLine(Canvas: TCanvas; const AX1, AY1, AX2, AY2: real; const LineColor: TColor);

var
  swapped: boolean;

  procedure plot(const x, y, c: real);
  var
    resclr: TColor;
  begin
    if swapped then
      resclr := Canvas.Pixels[round(y), round(x)]
    else
      resclr := Canvas.Pixels[round(x), round(y)];
    resclr := RGB(round(GetRValue(resclr) * (1-c) + GetRValue(LineColor) * c),
                  round(GetGValue(resclr) * (1-c) + GetGValue(LineColor) * c),
                  round(GetBValue(resclr) * (1-c) + GetBValue(LineColor) * c));
    if swapped then
      Canvas.Pixels[round(y), round(x)] := resclr
    else
      Canvas.Pixels[round(x), round(y)] := resclr;
  end;

  function rfrac(const x: real): real; inline;
  begin
    rfrac := 1 - frac(x);
  end;

  procedure swap(var a, b: real);
  var
    tmp: real;
  begin
    tmp := a;
    a := b;
    b := tmp;
  end;

var
  x1, x2, y1, y2, dx, dy, gradient, xend, yend, xgap, xpxl1, ypxl1,
  xpxl2, ypxl2, intery: real;
  x: integer;

begin

  x1 := AX1;
  x2 := AX2;
  y1 := AY1;
  y2 := AY2;

  dx := x2 - x1;
  dy := y2 - y1;
  swapped := abs(dx) < abs(dy);
  if swapped then
  begin
    swap(x1, y1);
    swap(x2, y2);
    swap(dx, dy);
  end;
  if x2 < x1 then
  begin
    swap(x1, x2);
    swap(y1, y2);
  end;

  gradient := dy / dx;

  xend := round(x1);
  yend := y1 + gradient * (xend - x1);
  xgap := rfrac(x1 + 0.5);
  xpxl1 := xend;
  ypxl1 := floor(yend);
  plot(xpxl1, ypxl1, rfrac(yend) * xgap);
  plot(xpxl1, ypxl1 + 1, frac(yend) * xgap);
  intery := yend + gradient;

  xend := round(x2);
  yend := y2 + gradient * (xend - x2);
  xgap := frac(x2 + 0.5);
  xpxl2 := xend;
  ypxl2 := floor(yend);
  plot(xpxl2, ypxl2, rfrac(yend) * xgap);
  plot(xpxl2, ypxl2 + 1, frac(yend) * xgap);

  for x := round(xpxl1) + 1 to round(xpxl2) - 1 do
  begin
    plot(x, floor(intery), rfrac(intery));
    plot(x, floor(intery) + 1, frac(intery));
    intery := intery + gradient;
  end;

end;
```

To use this function, simply provide the canvas to draw to (in a manner rather similar to the Windows GDI functions that require a device context (DC)), and specify the initial and final points on the line. Notice that the code above draws a *black* line, and that the background *has to be white*. It is not difficult to generalize this to any situation, not even alpha-transparent drawings. Simply adjust the `plot` function, in which `c \in [0, 1]` is the *opacity* of the pixel at `(x, y)`.

Example usage:

Create a new VCL project and add

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  DrawAntialisedLine(Canvas, Width div 2, Height div 2, X, Y, clBlack);
end;
```

[[image: Click to magnify]
(Magnify)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/aaline.png)

## OpenGL

If you need high-performance and high-quality rendering in 2D or 3D, and you do all the drawing yourself, then OpenGL is generally the best choice. It is very easy to write an OpenGL application in Delphi. See http://privat.rejbrand.se/smooth.exe for an example I made in just ten minutes. Use the right mouse button to toggle between filled polygons and outlines, and click and hold the left mouse button to shoot!

## Update

I just made the code work on a coloured background (for instance, a photograph).

[[image: Click to magnify]
(Magnify)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/aabkg.png)

## Update - The Ultra-Fast Method

The above code is rather slow because the `Bitmap.Pixels` property is amazingly slow. When I work with graphics, I always represent a bitmap using a two-dimensional array of colour values, which is much, much, much faster. And when I am done with the image, I convert it to a GDI bitmap. I also have a function that creates a pixmap array from a GDI bitmap.

I modified the code above to draw on an array instead of a GDI bitmap, and the result is promising:

- Time required to render 100 lines
- GDI Bitmap:    2.86 s
- Pixel array:   0.01 s

If we let

```
type
  TPixmap = array of packed array of RGBQUAD;
```

and define

```
procedure TForm3.DrawAntialisedLineOnPixmap(var Pixmap: TPixmap; const AX1, AY1, AX2, AY2: real; const LineColor: TColor);
var
  swapped: boolean;

  procedure plot(const x, y, c: real);
  var
    resclr: TRGBQuad;
  begin
    if swapped then
    begin
      if (x < 0) or (y < 0) or (x >= ClientWidth) or (y >= ClientHeight) then
        Exit;
      resclr := Pixmap[round(y), round(x)]
    end
    else
    begin
      if (y < 0) or (x < 0) or (y >= ClientWidth) or (x >= ClientHeight) then
        Exit;
      resclr := Pixmap[round(x), round(y)];
    end;
    resclr.rgbRed := round(resclr.rgbRed * (1-c) + GetRValue(LineColor) * c);
    resclr.rgbGreen := round(resclr.rgbGreen * (1-c) + GetGValue(LineColor) * c);
    resclr.rgbBlue := round(resclr.rgbBlue * (1-c) + GetBValue(LineColor) * c);
    if swapped then
      Pixmap[round(y), round(x)] := resclr
    else
      Pixmap[round(x), round(y)] := resclr;
  end;

  function rfrac(const x: real): real; inline;
  begin
    rfrac := 1 - frac(x);
  end;

  procedure swap(var a, b: real);
  var
    tmp: real;
  begin
    tmp := a;
    a := b;
    b := tmp;
  end;

var
  x1, x2, y1, y2, dx, dy, gradient, xend, yend, xgap, xpxl1, ypxl1,
  xpxl2, ypxl2, intery: real;
  x: integer;

begin

  x1 := AX1;
  x2 := AX2;
  y1 := AY1;
  y2 := AY2;

  dx := x2 - x1;
  dy := y2 - y1;
  swapped := abs(dx) < abs(dy);
  if swapped then
  begin
    swap(x1, y1);
    swap(x2, y2);
    swap(dx, dy);
  end;
  if x2 < x1 then
  begin
    swap(x1, x2);
    swap(y1, y2);
  end;

  gradient := dy / dx;

  xend := round(x1);
  yend := y1 + gradient * (xend - x1);
  xgap := rfrac(x1 + 0.5);
  xpxl1 := xend;
  ypxl1 := floor(yend);
  plot(xpxl1, ypxl1, rfrac(yend) * xgap);
  plot(xpxl1, ypxl1 + 1, frac(yend) * xgap);
  intery := yend + gradient;

  xend := round(x2);
  yend := y2 + gradient * (xend - x2);
  xgap := frac(x2 + 0.5);
  xpxl2 := xend;
  ypxl2 := floor(yend);
  plot(xpxl2, ypxl2, rfrac(yend) * xgap);
  plot(xpxl2, ypxl2 + 1, frac(yend) * xgap);

  for x := round(xpxl1) + 1 to round(xpxl2) - 1 do
  begin
    plot(x, floor(intery), rfrac(intery));
    plot(x, floor(intery) + 1, frac(intery));
    intery := intery + gradient;
  end;

end;
```

and the conversion functions

```
var
  pixmap: TPixmap;

procedure TForm3.CanvasToPixmap;
var
  y: Integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin

  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SetSize(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

    BitBlt(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SetLength(pixmap, ClientHeight, ClientWidth);
    for y := 0 to ClientHeight - 1 do
      CopyMemory(@(pixmap[y][0]), Bitmap.ScanLine[y], ClientWidth * sizeof(RGBQUAD));

  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm3.PixmapToCanvas;
var
  y: Integer;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;

  try
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bitmap.SetSize(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);

    for y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
      CopyMemory(Bitmap.ScanLine[y], @(Pixmap[y][0]), ClientWidth * sizeof(RGBQUAD));

    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Bitmap);

  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;

end;
```

then we can write

```
procedure TForm3.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin

  // Get the canvas as a bitmap, and convert this to a pixmap
  CanvasToPixmap;

  // Draw on this pixmap (very fast!)
  for i := 0 to 99 do
    DrawAntialisedLineOnPixmap(pixmap, Random(ClientWidth), Random(ClientHeight), Random(ClientWidth), Random(ClientHeight), clRed);

  // Convert the pixmap to a bitmap, and draw on the canvas
  PixmapToCanvas;

end;
```

which will render 100 anti-aliased lines on the form, in less than one hundredth of a second.

There seems to be a small bug in the code, though, probably in the Canvas -> Pixmap function. But right now I am way too tired to debug (just got home from work).

Comment: This is really slow, and is a proof of concept more than a useful function. Playing with metafiles need a lot of commands, much more than only line drawing. You should go and see http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas for example or http://graphics32.org/wiki for a more complete drawing library.

Comment: Or of course, use GdiPlus, which is shipped with every Windows since XP.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: I do not understand what you are talking about. I do not play with metafiles. But it is well-known that the `Pixels` property is slow. If one would draw the line on a two-dimensional array of pixels, and then use the `scanline` property to convert to/from the canvas, you could probably improve the performance significantly. But if you do not need to draw more than (say) a hundred lines, this is "fast enough" as it stands.

Comment: @Andreas: You're right, I spoke about metafiles because it's a way of having all TCanvas methods. But since the request was about lines, your code is good. But what if some other commands are needed in the future? How to easily implement not black&white drawing, or draw a line on a background picture? The more open it is, the better. GdiPlus, http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas or http://graphics32.org/wiki are complete, and get the work done.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: Drawing lines with semi-transparent anti-aliasing on a non-uniform background is trivial using only a minor modification to mmy code above. Indeed, `c` is the transparency of the pixel, and given background colour, forground colour, and transparency, blending is trivial. But of course, depending on your needs, a full library might be needed. But I got the impression that the OP wanted something light-weight just to draw straight lines.

Comment: @Andreas- Yes, I need something simple and compact. I already use Graphics32 but this is overkill. OpenGL is neither small, neither compact :)    But the source code provided is the best answer until now.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks for your code. It is the most simple and most elegant solution!!!! But (I hope I am not a rude brat) can you give few more clues about how to start in making the code to support colors? I am not really into graphics. I am not asking for code (you already did a lot) only some hints about how to start. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andreas - PS: I have seen your web site ( http://english.rejbrand.se/AlgoSim ). Impressive. It seems you are really into graphics.

Comment: @Altar: Thank you. I updated the code so that it will work on a variable, coloured background.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I compared the code and now I see it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Andreas - I get 'Range check error' in procedure plot. It works however, if you just ignore the error with {$R-}. Anyway, I just realized that the function is too slow for the amount of lines I want to draw.

Comment: @Altar: Yes, the `TBitmap.Pixels` property is amazingly slow. Therefore, when I work with graphics, I do all pixel manipulation on a two-dimensional array of integers (TColors, or TRGBQUADs), and then, when I am done and want to display the bitmap, I convert the array to a normal GDI bitmap. I updated with some code that illustrates the idea. There seems to be a minor bug in the code, but at the moment I am way too tired to debug.

Comment: +1, looks like a really interesting (if not complex to me) answer!!

Comment: @Andreas, have you tried to measure the speed between your pixel array way and e.g. GDI+ antialiased line rendering ? I'm asking just for curiosity...

Comment: gradient needs to be computed like this because dx could be sometimes 0:   if Dx=0
  then gradient:= dy
  else gradient:= dy / dx;

Comment: how to increase the width of the line?

Answer (score 11):

I believe GDI+ does anti-aliased drawing (by default), I don't know if recent Delphi versions have a GdiPlus.pas, but there are [copies available online](http://google.com/codesearch?q=gdiplus+lang:pascal).

Comment: GDI+ doesn't do anti-aliasing of GDI EMF/TMetaFile/Canvas content. It only renders anti-aliasing with GDI+/EMF+/Canvas metafiles. So in order to use anti-aliasing, you'll have to rewrite all you drawings using GDI+ methods. Our GdiPlus library allows anti-aliased drawings using "normal" VCL canvas commands: draw into a TMetaFile, then write it using our library. It's fast and easy.

Comment: I read too fast. For drawing just lines, you can use GdiPlus methods. But you'll have to learn about GdiPlus drawing, whereas with our library you'll use plain old VCL TCanvas methods, just as usual. If you'd like to use GdiPlus drawing, I recommend using the http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml library, which is much easier to use than previous conversions, but requires Delphi 2009/2010/XE.

Comment: @Bouchez - does it work on systems previous to WinXP? does it works on ALL WinXP OSs or the user has to install some updates?

Comment: Sorry. Forget about it. Does fit my requirements (D7).

Comment: Our SynGdiPlus library work with Delphi 7 up to Delphi 2010. It works on all Windows since XP (even without Service Pack), and you'll have to deploy a gdiplus.dll if you want your application work with Windows 2000 (it will search for gdiplus.dll in the Office folder, also). If the gdiplus.dll is not available, it will use normal GDI to draw, and your code will work (since the library is dynamically linked to the exe, whereas all other gdiplus libraries I know use static linking), but with no anti-aliaising.

Comment: drawing to a bitmap via a metafile as this library does is, sadly, terribly slow. Graphics32 is the best option that I have found.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [TAgg2D](http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/documentation/index.html). It is a simplified API for 2D drawing over AggPas. So you can use simple functions like:

- Line  (x1, y1, x2, y2 )
- Rectangle  (x1, y1, x2, y2 )
- RoundedRect (x1, y1, x2, y2, r )

Easy!

Answer (score 3):

Give a try to [Anti-Grain Geometry library](http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/)

Comment: This library seems complex. Do you know if I can use it as simply as DrawAntiAliasLine()? Or I have to perform complex stunts like I have to do with Graphics32?

Answer (score 3):

Download [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org). Create a new TBitmap32 instance. Call the TBitmap32.RenderText method:

```
procedure TBitmap32.RenderText(X, Y: Integer; const Text: String; AALevel: Integer; Color: TColor32);
```

`if AALevel > -1` then you should get anti-aliased text.

When you're done writing string(s) on your TBitmap32 instance, then you can draw this TBitmap32 instance to any Canvas using the DrawTo method:

```
procedure TBitmap32.DrawTo(hDst: HDC; DstX, DstY: Integer);
```

Comment: Please read my post again. I am doing this already. What I need is "I need a very simple library to draw a bunch of lines with anti-aliasing. It has to follow Delphi paradigm: self contained and SYSTEM INDEPENDENT (no DLL hell), fast, simple."

Comment: I believe Graphics32 meets most (if not all) of your requests. It is self-contained, platform-independent (Free Pascal and Lazarus on Windows and OSX), and pretty fast. Whether or not it is simple enough, well I guess that's the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Most but not all. This is why I changing it. If it would have meet all my requirements I wouldn't have been posting here. Right?  -  To make it simple: I want something better than Graphics32.

Comment: @Altar Graphics32 does meet all of your needs and I have no idea why you are rejecting it. There are no DLLs. There is nothing to install. It's simple to use. It's fast.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the products that I am aware of:

1. [DtpDocument](http://www.simdesign.nl/) Very good Vector Editor. Lot's of features. Anti-Aliasing supported very well. Commercial Solution
2. [ImageEn](http://www.hicomponents.com/) It's fast enough for me. Commercial Solution
3. [Cairo Graphics](http://cairographics.org/) It's very fast and used by Mozilla in Firefox for rendering. You can easily use Cairo in Delphi by [this](http://www.rodi.dk/programming_cairo.php) tutorial. I strongly recommend you take a shot.

Answer (score 1):

There is BGRABitmap for Delphi
https://github.com/bgrabitmap/BGRABitmapDelphi

BGRABitmap originally a Lazarus FPC library, now works with Delphi VCL and is full featured having antialiasing and transparency.